# Best method to create a sub array from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array say `a[3]={1,2,5}` . I have to create another array `a2[2]={2,5}`.

What I have tried is to just create a new array `a2[]` and just copy all the elements from the required position range.

Is there any other method to accomplish this in C?.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
memcpy(a2, &a[1], 2*sizeof(*a));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `memcpy(&a2, &a[1], 2*sizeof(*a));` ?

Comment: No, a2 is already a pointer to array but a[i] is number instead.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of having a second array, just use a pointer:

```
int a[3]={1,2,5};
int *p = &a[1];
```

If they have to be distinct, you have no choice other than to copy the array elements into a new array.