# Create a subarray or slice in C without the last element

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to write a shell using C.

I have managed to process and parse user input into an array, for example. If the user inputs `ls -al`, it is parsed as an array of `|ls|al|\0|`

One of the requirements for this tiny shell is to be able to fork and execute processes using `fork()` and `execvp` (or one of the other `exec` functions), and be able to background processes when the user inputs the `&` ampersand symbol.

The [execvp()](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/exec.html) system call requires 2 arguments:

1. The character array pointer (ahem, string) that contains the name of the file to be executed (which would be first element of my parsed array
2. The argument char array to be passed to the program being executed.

**Here's the issue**, how to I create a subarray from the argument array I created **without the last element in the array**? i.e If the user types in `ls -al &` which my shell generates an array of `|ls|al|&|`, **I need to pass a argv array of `|al|` only, without the `|&|`.**

Based on my experience with C and what I've found, a can use a *pointer* if I don't want the first element of an array, like `char** subArray = &argv[1]` or use `memcpy` ([SO Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763408/best-method-to-create-a-sub-array-from-an-array-in-c)) which allows a subarray to be created without the first n elements, but not without the last element.

But to remove the last element is **a for-loop or while-loop the only way?** Where a new array will be created without the last element.

**I've also tried setting the last element** where `&` resides to `NULL` or `\0`,  <s>but execvp does not allow arrays with a NULL value to be passed in (it crashes the program).</s> This works as intended. But doesn't actually create a subArray or a pointer of it.

A related concept I'm looking for is probably *array slicing* in other languages, which I don't think exists in C.

Comment: "execvp does not allow arrays with a NULL value to be passed in" -- on the contrary, `execvp()` *requires* the argument array to be terminated by an element with value `NULL`.  If that seems to cause your program to misbehave then something is dreadfully wrong.  Do present an MCVE if you want any assistance, as I can't imagine what you may have done to evoke the behavior you describe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger great point. It crashed ls (when I replaced '&' with '\0'), but I attempted that again with NULL and that works as intended.  I'll delete the question then. Though for the question still stands, for subarrays is there any way create one without the need for a for/while loop?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes but a function that only expects an array to have 1 and 2 will have access to 3 as well. Which is what I am trying to avoid. Given that my question was due to my misunderstanding and there isn't a need for a subarray, should I delete/rephrase the question?

Comment: @matrixanomaly The C language doesn't provide any way to keep functions from accessing stuff they shouldn't access. All the code is supposed to cooperate, not be at war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` family of functions does not work as most programmers expect.

The first argument has the executable file path.  The second argument should *also* be to the file path (or the filename only portion of it).  The third argument is the first parameter, etc.

In the case of the *execvp* flavor, the argument array still must have the first entry point to the executable file path.

You do not need to do any *slicing*:  just put a NULL in the array after the last argument pointer.

Comment: Selecting this as the answer given it was the earliest and concise. Please advise on how I should (if I should) rename my question (since it is more on exec and not subarrays)

Answer (score 1):

Just null the last argument.

```
argv[argc-1] = NULL;
execvep(cmd, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you need to do. A dynamically-constructed C array is just a pointer to its first element with the other elements in the right place. An array containing "1", "2", "3" is already also an array containing "1", "2" and an array containing just "1".

In the case of the exec functions, they require an array whose last entry is a NULL (that's how they figure out which entry is the last). So to convert `{ "1", "2", "3" }` to `{ "1", "2", NULL }`, just set the third entry to NULL.